# Is PA provably definable?

Tags: logic, peano-axioms, incompleteness

> A set of sentences $S$ from the language of arithmetic is called *definable* if there is a formula $\phi(x)$ such that $\mathbb{N} \models \phi(n)$ iff $n$ is the Gödel number of a formula from $S$.

A stronger notion:

> $S$ is called *provably definable* if there is a formula $\phi(x)$ such that $PA \vdash \phi(n)$ iff $n$ is the gödel number of a member of $S$ and $PA \vdash \neg \phi(n)$ otherwise.

I know that PA is definable. However it seems that some of the provability rules used in the proof of Gödel's theorem require PA to be provably definable, e.g.

> For any sentence $\phi$, if $PA \vdash \phi$ then $PA \vdash Pr_{PA}(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$.

Here $Pr_{PA}$ denotes the provability predicate. So is PA provably definable and how might one prove this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If the set of theorems of $\sf PA$ were provably definable by the formula $\phi(x),$ then we could use the diagonalization lemma to find a sentence $S$ such that $ \mathsf{PA}\vdash S\leftrightarrow \lnot \phi(\ulcorner S\urcorner).$ But then we have  $$\ulcorner S\urcorner \in \operatorname{Th}(\mathsf{PA}) \iff \mathsf{PA}\vdash S \iff \mathsf{PA}\vdash \lnot\phi(\ulcorner S\urcorner)  \iff \ulcorner S\urcorner \notin \operatorname{Th}(\mathsf{PA}).$$

The example you give just means that $\sf PA$ can prove all *positive* instances of membership in $\operatorname{Th}(\sf PA) $, not necessarily the negative ones.

In fact, the provably definable sets are exactly the computable sets, whereas $\operatorname{Th}(\sf PA)$ is a set that is computably enumerable but not computable.

Comment: Right, thanks! My lecturer assumes provable definability in his proof of the provability rule I stated, so I am still a little confused. The exact theorem my lecturer claims is: " For any provably definable set S and any sentence $\phi$, $PA \vdash Pr_S(\phi$). So he wouldn't be able to apply this rule with $S = PA$, as you argued. Do you know how to remedy this? Many thanks.

Comment: @user I assume you mean for any provably definable set $S$ and sentence $\phi$ such that $S\vdash \phi$? I think the clash is axioms vs theorems. I thought you were asking if the set of theorems of PA were provably definable and answered on that basis (let me edit to make that clearer). But the (usual) set of axioms of PA is provably definable.

Comment: Yes, I do indeed mean only the collection of axioms. I realized that just now as well. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @user In that case, this follows from the fact that any computable set is provably definable (and the usual presentation of the axioms of PA is computable).

Comment: That's cleared up my problem. Thanks. I guess manually one would show that terms, formulae, sequence of formulae etc. are all provably definable!?

Comment: @user Yeah, it's a tedious verification like that if you're going to show it directly, in full detail.

Comment: @user Like first you'd show that you can prove when $n$ is the Godel number of a sentence (as opposed to some arbitrary expression), then you'd show that you can prove when that sentence happens to be an axiom of PA. This last step would be trivial if there were only a finite number of axioms (could just list the axioms and decide if it is one of them), but for PA would also need to think about how to confirm if a sentence is an instance of the induction schema.

Comment: As I said you've cleared up my issue, so feel free to ignore. I reread your post and you say that the provability rule is the positive direction. I guess explicitly you mean that $PA \vdash Pr_{PA}(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner) \iff PA \vdash \phi$ is true but $PA \vdash \neg Pr_{PA}(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner) \iff PA \vdash \neg \phi$ is false ( and that's why the set of theorems is not provably definable)?!

Comment: @user What I mean is that the example you give says "for any theorem of PA, PA proves the theorem is provable", whereas if the theorems of PA were provably definable, we would have that, *plus* "For any sentence that is not a theorem of PA, PA proves the sentence is not provable."